# Send $_POST with php and redirect the browser to the resulting page

Tags: php, post, curl, header

How to send $_POST and go to posting page

I'm trying

```
$rCurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($rCurl, CURLOPT_URL, SECUREURL.basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
curl_setopt ($rCurl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($rCurl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($rCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt ($rCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sPostData);
curl_setopt ($rCurl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//$sHtmlResult = curl_exec ($rCurl);
curl_exec ($rCurl);
curl_close($rCurl);
```

but results return to page and nothing redirect ot destination page whit result

How to send $_POST data and going to posting page like this

```
header("Location:".SECUREURL.basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."?".$sPostData);
```

Comment: Andrew has not accepted any of the answers to the questions he's asked. Mind you, there are only 7.

Comment: Sorry, Col. Shrapnel, but I voted to answers, what I need do else - I don't understand

Comment: oh.. all right, accpeted

Answer (score 0):

What does your $sPostData look like?

I use the following to encode arrays for CURL before POSTing. $post contains an associative array of POST fields.

```
foreach($post as $key=>$value) { 
  $postString  .= urlencode($key) . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&'; 
}
rtrim($postString,'&');
```

Then:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($post));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
```

The idea is that CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS should look like a GET string and URL encoded.

You may also need to set CURLOPT_USERAGENT, CURLOPT_ENCODING, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.  For debugging you can enable CURLOPT_HEADER, CURLOPT_HEADER and CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT.

Comment: even using such example - the result return to first page

Answer (score -1):

HTTP POST from PHP, without cURL

you may try `stream_context_create`

```
$message = 'success'
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"POST",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n",
    'content' => http_build_query(array('status' => $message))
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

/* Sends an http request to www.example.com
   with additional headers shown above and post the status */
$file = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/", false, $http_options);
```

Answer (score -1):

**This. Is. Impossible.**

I hope it is clear enough to stop further answers from people who don't bother to read the question.

Comment: Pretty amazing that something VBScript could do in 2001 is totally impossible in PHP

Comment: Pretty amazing that people have no idea of the difference between a server and a browser.

Comment: VBScript can run on a server. Not sure what point you're trying to make.

How to do this in server-side VBScript: http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=126519.0

Comment: So you are yet another fellow who can't read the question body. Why I am not surprised?

Comment: I edited the question title especially for your kind.

Comment: The link you posted says nothing of redirect or even a browser. Which is no wonder because of the protocol limitations, regardless of the implementation.